# WCF service supported authentication displays empty string?

Tags: authentication, wcf

So, I am trying to fix an service that used to work before. I am trying with Basic authentication, but I get this response. I can't figure out what is wrong, I suspect customer has changed supported authentication methods, but the project folk can't seemingly tell me what are supported, even though asking.

This is the exception response what I get when calling the service:

[image]

Normally it documents the supported authentication header as 'Basic', or something else.

I do not know what it really means when the service answers returns an empty string like that. Is it misconfigured, or does it implicitly mean something?

Whole code:

```
                // Create the binding.
                var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding()
                {
                    ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0),
                    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000000,
                    Security =
                    {
                        Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
                        Transport =
                        {
                            ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic, 
                            ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic
                        },
                    }
                };

                var ea = new
                    EndpointAddress(ConnectionStringOptions.SAPMEMaterialListEndPoint);

                var materialList = (List<MaterialListItem>)await FetchDataPersistently(async () =>
                {
                    // Create the client.
                    var cc = new XacuteWSSoapClient(myBinding, ea);
                    // The client must provide a user name and password. The code
                    // to return the user name and password is not shown here. Use
                    // a database to store the user name and passwords, or use the
                    // ASP.NET Membership provider database.
                    cc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ConnectionStringOptions.OneERPUser;
                    cc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConnectionStringOptions.OneERPPassword;

                    var response = await cc.XacuteAsync(ConnectionStringOptions.OneERPUser,
                    ConnectionStringOptions.OneERPPassword, new InputParams
                    {
                        Site = ConnectionStringOptions.OneERPSite
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

We can follow these steps to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Determine if the username and password are correct.
2. It is recommended that the wcf service be hosted on a Windows service and that IIS intercept https requests.
3. Change your security scheme to TransportWithMessageCredentia. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-transport-security-and-message-credentials?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.